# How to pass a List as param from one JSP to an included JSP in Struts 2?

Tags: jsp, struts2, tiles, struts-tags, valuestack

Imagine you want this the JSP code fragment below to be in multiple pages, where the only thing that varies is the list that is passed to it (`xxx` in the example).

```jsp
<s:iterator value="%{#xxx}" var="module" status="stat">
  <s:property value="#module.name"/>            
</s:iterator>
```

My first idea would be to put it in `myFragment.jsp` and use `s:include` in other pages to include it, and pass the list as an `s:param`, like:

```jsp
<s:include value="/myFragment.jsp">
  <s:param name="xxx" value="%{#myModules}"></s:param>
</s:include>
```

The problem is that `<s:param>` seems to pass only strings, so the above code doesn't work.

I've also tried to use `<s:set var="myParam">${param.xxx}</s:set>` (and try to put `myParam` in the iterator, but without luck.

**Questions:**

1. What would be the correct way to to this?
2. Is there a more elegant solution for this case where you want to remove code duplication in your JSPs by refactoring common code to a unified location?

**Edit (example):**

- Example where you have `Page1.jsp` and `Page2.jsp`. Both use a very similar `s:iterator`, the only difference being variable passed to it. The goal is to refactor the `s:iterator` to someplace so that you only write it once.

Naturally in real life there is more code than just the `s:iterator` to be refactored.

**Page1.jsp:**

```jsp
<s:action name="MyAction" var="xxx"></s:action>
<s:iterator value="%{#xxx}" var="module" status="stat">
  <s:property value="#module.name"/>            
</s:iterator>
```

**Page2.jsp:**

```jsp
<s:iterator value="%{#variableFromStack.modules}" var="module" status="stat">
  <s:property value="#module.name"/>            
</s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason to pass parameters to the [s:include](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/include-tag.html) tag. Note, that parameters are accessed only as request params:

> Parameters are passed as request parameters, so use the `${param.ParamName}` notation to access them. Do not use the `s:property` tag to access parameters in included files.

---

*The correct way is to push parameters on the `valueStack`.*

The elegant solution is to use Tiles framework.

> Tiles is a *templating* framework designed to easily allow the creation of web application pages with a consistent look and feel. It can be used for both page decorating and *componentization*.

---

There are [Tiles 2](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/tiles/) and [Tiles 3](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/tiles-3/) integration plugins.

Comment: I am actually using tiles2 in the application. However, I am not sure it would work in this situation: 1. myModules has just been loaded via s:action before the s:include - if you use tiles to decorate it there, how would you pass the myModules variable?
Thanks in advance for the reply. I am curious to think about this tiles alternative, although a bit unsure it is used to pass such small fragments of jsp code...

Comment: You can use attributes but `s:action` before the `s:include` can't work.  Also it's unclear how did you use them.

Comment: see the example I added to the original question, to clarify the use case.

Comment: I would just use `modules` getter, in real life more code has to be included, the `action` tag is doing almost the same, but it is not cheap.

Comment: Sorry, did not get what you meant. What getter? And where would you extract the iterator to (based on your Tiles suggestion, or other)? Could you exemplify in https://jsfiddle.net/mmalmeida/jx5xvteb/1/ ?

Comment: When you access the object from the value stack you use OGNL and it works with `getXxx()` method that returns an object. Tiles works a bit differently but you can use request scope. And jsfiddle doesn't work with either tiles or struts.